# How to remove last draw circleView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have created code that generates multiple `CircleView`. I can move them with touch as well.

With a delete button I want to remove the last drawn circle on click.

I have written code to delete it, but it doesn't remove the last drawn cirlcleview.

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var circleView = CircleView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
    let circleWidth = CGFloat(100)
    var lastCircleCenter = CGPoint()
    var currentCenter = CGPoint()
    var newCircleViews : [CircleView] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        circleView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    @IBAction func deleteButtonAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let _ = newCircleViews.popLast()
        circleView.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: view) else {
            return
        }
//
//        //dont create new circle if touch is existing circle
        if let draggedCircle = newCircleViews.filter({ $0.frame.intersects(CGRect(x: point.x, y: point.y, width: 0, height: 0)) }).first {
                    self.circleView = draggedCircle
                    return
                }

        let offset = circleWidth / 2
        let rect = CGRect(x: point.x - offset, y: point.y - offset, width: circleWidth, height: circleWidth)
        let circleViews = CircleView(frame: rect)
        newCircleViews.append(circleViews)
        view.addSubview(circleViews)
        // The newly created view can be immediately dragged
        circleView = circleViews

    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
      //  circleView = nil

    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


        guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: view) else {
            return
        }
        circleView.center = point

    }

}
```

**CircleView file**

```
import UIKit

class CircleView: UIView {      // using view

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .clear
    }


    required init(coder aDecoder : NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder : ) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(){

            context.setLineWidth(2)
            UIColor.yellow.set()


            let circleCenter = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.self.height / 2)
            let circleRadius = (frame.size.width - 10) / 2

            context.addArc(center: circleCenter, radius: circleRadius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi * 2, clockwise: true)

            context.strokePath()

            
        }
    }
  //  func undo(){
  //      self.setNeedsDisplay()

 //   }


}
```

[my View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuiX1.png)

Comment: Where is the code for your delete button? Is it in your `undoButtoAction()` IBAction? (That is a very confusing name for a delete button function if so.)

Comment: @DuncanC - yes undoButtoAction(), but i have renamed to deleteButtonAction().

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
let _ = newCircleViews.popLast()
```

removes the last object (a `CircleView`) from the array.

But, that's all that happens. It doesn't remove the **view** from the view hierarchy.

You want to change your `deleteButtonAction()` func to this:

```
@IBAction func deleteButtonAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // remove the last view that was added to the array
    let lastCircleView = newCircleViews.popLast()
    // remove that view from the view hierarchy
    lastCircleView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: This. (+1). I figured that was what was going on, but couldn't be sure because the method name for the IBAction was confusing.